# Edit date field html

Tags: datetime

I would like to edit the html produced for a field. Is that possible to do this through a hook? I want to convert "date1 - date2" to "date1 to date2".

Comment: I notice you want to change it to 'to' but that is already the default. Or are they backwards in the question and you want '-'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the theme function for the date range date field formatter: [theme_date_display_range()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/theme_date_display_range/7).

For example, in your theme's template.php file you can add this:

```
/**
 * Override the themeing of a date field date range.
 */
function THEMENAME_date_display_range($variables) {
  $date1 = $variables['date1'];
  $date2 = $variables['date2'];
  $timezone = $variables['timezone'];
  $attributes_start = $variables['attributes_start'];
  $attributes_end = $variables['attributes_end'];

  // Wrap the result with the attributes.
  return t('!start-date - !end-date', array(
    '!start-date' => '<span class="date-display-start"' . drupal_attributes($attributes_start) . '>' . $date1 . '</span>', 
    '!end-date' => '<span class="date-display-end"' . drupal_attributes($attributes_end) . '>' . $date2 . $timezone . '</span>',
  ));
}
```

Replace THEMENAME with the name of your theme.

Note in the return line the dash.
The default is for that to be 'to'.

Comment: Hey @rooby, thanks for tip. I need to make it theme independent, applying this through a module

Comment: @PotneySwitters You'll need to use [`hook_theme_registry_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7) for that